# How to count specific number of a certain key in an object array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, count

I'm completely stumped on this one.  I'm trying to figure out how many times I can count the occurrence of a specific key in an object array.

Here is the array:

```
Array 
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [user_id] => 1
        [group_id] => 1
        [cat_0] => foo
        [cat_1] => bar
        [cat_2] => 
        [cat_3] => 
    )
)
```

You see that cat_ appears four times but with different numbers on the end of it ranging from 0-3.  This number may change and be dynamic, so I need a way to figure out how to return a count of 4, for the 4 keys of "cat_".  Any thoughts?  Or a good direction to point me in?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Initialize a counter. Iterate through each value in your array, check if it starts with `cat_` and if yes, increment a counter.

Comment: Can the array contain multiple objects?  If so, do you want to count all occurrences of cat_*, the max, or something else?

Comment: Array is as shown above, and the max count of the number of times cat_ appears

Comment: Umm . . . so why is your Object in a single element Array?  Most of the answers below will work if you modify them to deal with array element 0 . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner option

```
$catCount = count(preg_grep("/^cat_(\d)+$/", array_keys(get_object_vars($yourObj))));
```

[`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) can scan through arrays for a pattern

referenced: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1337711/138383

Comment: That's an object, not an array . . . might work with get_object_vars instead of array_keys.  That will also only work if the indexes aren't sparse.

Comment: Scanned right over that one, seems `get_object_vars` gets it. Updated code

Comment: @K_G Are you setting `$yourObj` to your array or object value?

Comment: even added (object) to the beginning of the array variable and still returns count of zero

Comment: Array being used is as above in question, here is what I did with yours,$select = (object)$select;
      $catCount = count(preg_grep("/^cat_(\d)+$/", array_keys(get_object_vars($select))));

Comment: Probably change that to $yourObj[0], since OP seems to just want to copy and paste code, and not try to read/understand why it might be failing . . .

Comment: @K_G try using just `$select[0]` since that seems to be your object

Answer (score 3):

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($myObj as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'cat_') === 0) {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

You should really make `'cat'` an array with sub-keys, that's a lot easier to work with.

Comment: Additionally, you could check that `$value !== null` if you need to only count fields with values.

Comment: @K_G Only if you don't know how to apply it properly. Works for me: http://3v4l.org/Q3k94

Comment: This should work, if $myObj is $myArray[0] - OP has an an array containing objects.

Comment: Yes I changed it to $array[0] and it worked. thank you ernie.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo-code for simple case:

```
for all keys:
1. Get the key
2. Apply regex to check if the key matches your prefix
3. if yes ++1 your result
```

if you need to find duplicates with unknown prefix,meaning you can have the following:

```
[random-prefix1_1] => v1
[random-prefix1_2] => v2
[random-prefix1_3] => v3
[random-prefix2_1] => v4
[random-prefix2_2] => v5
```

Then you can do this in reverse, meaning you can search the keys for postfix (_[0-9]+) and remove it and then count identical keys (order alphabetically and find when a key is different from the next one for example)

If both prefix and postfix are unknown, you have a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop form simple logic .below code work for array and if u want for obj use ->

```
    $j =1 ;
    for ($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){ //note here we consider that cat_0 is always there and if not then check isset out of for loop cat_0 exist then only go inside loop
          echo 'O/P : '.$val['cat_'$i];
          if (isset($val['cat_'.(int)($i+1)])){
               $j++;
          }
    }
```

and at last $j contain last value (total).
This will work for n no of cat_ .