# how to calculate number of values of key occurance in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [label] => A
        [uid] => 429
        [country_id] => 3
        [date] => 2015-02-11 13:55:34
        [DiffDate] => 20
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => A
        [uid] => 429
        [country_id] => 2
        [date] => 2015-02-11 13:55:34
        [DiffDate] => 20
    )
  ...... and so on
)
```

Now I have to calculate number of occurrences of country records example

```
country 1 has total 10 occurrence 
country 2 has total 20 occurrence
```

I need help as there are lot of arrays created also I am getting country id as different array

thanks in advance

Comment: foreach loop push into another container the id, array count values, or array column + array count values

Comment: you  can use the reference of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337637/count-similar-array-keys/1337711#1337711

Comment: Downvoters, please specify your reason.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels I assume it's "Does not show any research effort [methods/code attempted]; is not useful"

Comment: `array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'country_id'));`

Comment: @Saposhiente I have to disagree. This is a typical problem where a novice developer might struggle with.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels I did not personally downvote. In any case, the standards for downvoting are a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to tackle this. I like the following approach:

1. Restructure the array, so it's just a list of countries using [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/array_column)

   ```
   $countries = array_column($array, 'country_id');
   ```

or for PHP 5.4

```
    $countries = array_map(function($item) {
        return $item['country_id'];
    }, $array);
```

2. Use [`array_count_values`](http://www.php.net/array_count_values) to get the number of occurrences for each country

   ```
   $occurrences = array_count_values($countries);
   ```

---

#### Adding a country on a condition (alternative step 1)

If you need to do a check before adding the country to the `$countries` array, you're better of with a `foreach` loop than with `array_map`.

```
$countries = []
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item['DiffDate'] >= 3) $countries[] = $item['country_id'];
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but what if there would more condition such as number of days should be 3 then it creates difficulty in php 5.4

Comment: @Indra In that case do a `foreach` loop, instead of `array_map` and add an `if` statement.